# I accidentally deleted an iMovie project, but I recovered it. Now it is too blurry to see!

Tags: macbook-pro, video, restore, imovie

I accidentally deleted an iMovie event with an important school project within it, but I recovered it by going to Finder, then clicking Movies. I re-uploaded them to iMovie but now they are so blurry, I cannot see the video! Please help me revert it back to its original state of clarity in time for presentation date, being Monday!

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you only recovered the low-quality proxies.

The structure should be

- Project Name folder, containing

  - CurrentVersion.imovieevent file &
  - Profect Name.rcproject folder, containing

    1. Movies folder
    2. Project file
    3. Proxies folder
    4. QuickLook

That applies whether you have the old iMovie structure or the new one.
If you have the new structure that doesn't look like a folder, then right click the iMovie Library 'file' & select 'Show Package Contents' - then you will see the actual folder structure

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you are telling me to do. I went to the Movies folder and from there I can only click iMovie Events or iMovie Projects. If I click Events>> My new options are iMovie Dropbox or the event that contains the project I lost but in very poor quality. There is nothing in the iMovie Dropbox folder. If we go back to the start, click Movies, then click iMovie Projects, I only have the option to click "My First Project", an instructional guide to making a video on iMovie. In simple words can you help me revert the video back to its original, high quality? Im sorry!

Comment: You cannot "revert a video to high quality", you can find the original movies and reassemble the project.

Comment: Nevermind, the presentation date seems to be long gone...